# React-Native project not opening in Expo go app

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I m working on a react native project and now the project won't open on my android device.
I don't recall changing any settings or anything anywhere.

I tried opening projects from different systems on my Android device and its working.
So the problem is in my PC.

The error on the app while connecting is "Uncaught Error: java.net.Exception: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:19000". I tried changing the port (doesn't work).

I want to use LAN only and not tunnel as tunnel is slow and takes a lot of time, so help me fix this.

Feel free to ask for any other info. I really want this resolved.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you're connected to the same Wi-Fi network as your mobile device.
2. Sign in to the same Expo account on your computer and this app.
3. Check you have the latest version of Expo CLI.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Set the env var REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME to your ip.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try to open tunnel mode:
instead of `expo start`use :

```
 expo start --tunnel
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to open tunnel mode: instead of `expo start` use :

```
expo start --tunnel
```